# replace css class with my class on the fly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm rendering html like this

```
<div class="btn btn-pagination">
   <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
</div>
```

and on page load I want to replace `fa fa-angle-right` with `myClass`

so I tried

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('.btn.btn-pagination').children($('.fa.fa-angle-right').removeClass());
   $('.btn.btn-pagination').children().addClass('myClass');
})
```

this doesnt work, so what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: it is working quite ok what do you expect?

Comment: check https://jsfiddle.net/jmyejzn9/

Comment: @guradio obviously not :)

Comment: well in the fiddle i dont see any other class in the <i> except for myclass which your code does

Comment: $('.btn.btn-pagination').children($('.fa.fa-angle-right').removeClass()); has a misplaced ")". Move the last ")" to before ".removeClass"

Comment: Are you just downvoting without any explanation? This isn't costructive. By the way, have luck on your trouble...

Comment: @user1765862 i am wondering what output do you expect please do enlighten us.

Comment: You want to change the class, but what do you want to do after changing to new class, example u want to change the background-color or any other thing ??

Answer (score 0):

Although your code should work but better way to accomplish this(using better selector and jQuery chaining) is shown below.

Try this:-

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('.btn.btn-pagination').children('.fa.fa-angle-right').removeClass().addClass('myClass'); 
});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/KartikeyaKhosla/jmyejzn9/1/)

OR

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('div.btn.btn-pagination > i.fa.fa-angle-right').removeClass().addClass('myClass'); 
});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/KartikeyaKhosla/jmyejzn9/2/)

Answer (score 0):

A better solution should be accessing to the dom just once.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  return $('.btn.btn-pagination .fa.fa-angle-right')
    .removeClass()
    .addClass('foobaz')
  ;
});
```

```css
.foobaz { background: red; width: 200px; height: 100px; margin: 0 auto; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn btn-pagination">
  <div class="fa fa-angle-right"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Question! why do you use "return" there?  Wouldn't it work without it?

Comment: It works even without the `return` statement, I used it because I think it more readable, just habitude...

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div class="btn btn-pagination">
   <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".fa .fa-angle-right").addClass('myClass');
     $(".fa .fa-angle-right").removeClass('.fa-angle-right');
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Refer demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2691/wkx9vf5p/).

Please find code below:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="btn btn-pagination">
  <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.btn.btn-pagination > i').attr('class', 'myClass');
})
```